# Azure ARM Template for Dropdownn type Parameter

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I am creating a Azure ARM template to provision VMs based on the environmnet type; so created an array type parameter as below,

```
  "EnvironmentType": {
"type": "array",
        "defaultValue": [
            "Dev",
            "Test",
            "PreProd",
            "Prod"
        ]
```

},

But on Azure portal this parameter is rendered as textbox with comma separated values as shown in below screenshot.

[image]

How to get this parameter displayed as dropdown?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to get this parameter displayed as dropdown?

As bmoore-msft mentioned we could replace the `defaultValue` with `allowedValues` and `array` with `string`. We also could set the dropdownlist default value from the template. In your case, please have a try to use the following code. More details we could refer to the [Customize the template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-create-first-template?toc=%2Fazure%2Ftemplates%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fazure%2Ftemplates%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json#customize-the-template).

```
"parameters": {
  "EnvironmentType": {
    "type": "string",
    "allowedValues": [
        "Dev",
        "Test",
        "PreProd",
        "Prod"
    ],
    "defaultValue": "Dev",
    "metadata": {
      "description": "The type of replication to use for the EnvironmentType."
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace "defaultValue" with "allowedValues" and "array" with "string".